# Is it possible to paste an image on top of another in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am fairly new to OpenCv and am creating a program that will segment a shoe from its background using GrabCut algorithm, then I want to paste the shoe onto a white background but I am struggling at that part.

I tried **cv2.add()** to add the two images together but the two images have to be the same size and I can't guarantee that since the program prompts the user to upload the image.

I have also tried **whiteBgImg = 255 - grabCutImg** to make the background white where the shoe isn't but it seems to affect the final image which is a problem as I need to perform feature detection and matching on the image.

Thank you in advance for the advice! :)

Original image:
[Original Shoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o5Sc.jpg)

Final image (after grabcut and **whiteBgImg = 255 - grabCutImg** applied): [Grabcut Shoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H179H.jpg)

Comment: Your Grabcut Shoe already has a white background. Please clarify or post the correct image. Perhaps the place you hosted the image changed it to JPG which does not support transparency.

Comment: Hi, yes it has a white background but it has inverted the colour of the shoe which is a problem because I need it to be the original colour. I'm looking to either fix this problem or an alternate solution (maybe adding the grabcut image with a white background image)

Comment: I posted an answer below that takes care of it. If you skip my inversion of your input and provide the original input without the inversion, then my script should work as you asked.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

**Note that I invert your image to get back your original. Skip the invert if you start with your actual original before you inverted it.**

- Read the input and invert
- Convert to gray
- Threshold to make a mask
- Create a white image the size of the input
- Blend the two together with the shoe over the white using the mask to control which shows
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("shoe_inverted.jpg")

# invert the polarity
img = 255 - img

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold image and make 3 channels as mask
mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 32, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# create white image for background of result
white = np.full_like(img, (255,255,255))

# apply mask to img and white
result = np.where(mask!=0, img, white)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("shoe_inverted_inverted.jpg", img)
cv2.imwrite("shoe_mask.jpg", mask)
cv2.imwrite("shoe_result.jpg", result)

cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Inverted input to get back to your original:

[image]

Mask (after thresholding to clean the boundary):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put one image in front of the other image, you can do this as follows:

```
back_img[y_start:y_end,x_start:x_end] = front_img[y_start:y_end,x_start:x_end]
```

If you want to concat an image on the y axis, the images must be the same size. For this, you can look at [cv2.resize](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)) or you can create a blank image with [np.zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) to add padding to the image and "If you want to put one image in front of the other image" which I said in the first method.